# How to convert excel date to numeric value using Python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

How do I convert Excel date format to number in Python? I'm importing a number of Excel files into Pandas dataframe in a loop and some values are formatted incorrectly in Excel. For example, the number column is imported as date and I'm trying to convert this date value into numeric.

```
     Original               New
1912-04-26 00:00:00         4500
```

How do I convert the date value in original to the numeric value in new? I know this code can convert numeric to date, but is there any similar function that does the opposite?

```
df.loc[0]['Date']= xlrd.xldate_as_datetime(df.loc[0]['Date'], 0)
```

I tried to specify the data type when I read in the files and also tried to simply change the data type of the column to 'float' but both didn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to import the excel files using Pandas, using pd.read_excel()?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the number means the number of days from 1900-01-00.
Following code is to calculate how many days passed from 1900-01-00 until the given date.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'date': ['1912-04-26 00:00:00'],
    }
)

print(df)
#                  date
#0  1912-04-26 00:00:00

def date_to_int(given_date):
    given_date = datetime.strptime(given_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    base_date = datetime(1900, 1, 1) - timedelta(days=2)
    delta = given_date - base_date
    return delta.days


df['date'] = df['date'].apply(date_to_int)

print(df)
#   date
#0  4500
```

Comment: Thanks but I believe this does the opposite of what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to convert the excel date to number, not the other way around.

Comment: @sgrimes I realized that my code was opposite. Now I revised my code, so that the code resovle what you expected.

Comment: thank you so much for updating the code but I get this error message: TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime

Comment: @sgrimes That is because I thought the value is `str`. If `given_date` 's type is already 'datetime` in your code, you don't need to use datetime.strptime(). Just remove the first line in the function, date_to_int().